# Identify user when receiving access token in web API using ADFS 2019 (oid claim)

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, openid, adfs, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to request an access token from ADFS 2019 containing an unique user-identifier which represents the same user across multiple applications.

I want to fetch an access token as a native client in order to request data from my web API. In order to return user-specific data, the access token needs to contain an user-identifier for the user who fetched the token from ADFS and sent it in the header of his request to the web API. The web API can then identify the requesting user.

Currently, the only user-identifier which the access token contains is the `sub` claim. Unfortunately, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#payload-claims), the `sub` claim is not the same identifier for a user across multiple applications. Since I need user-identifiers in order to link user-dependent data with users in a database which is used by several applications, I need an unique user-identifier which always represents the same user, no matter the application. According to the link above, what I am looking for should be the `oid` claim, but it is currently not contained by the access token I receive.

How can I add the `oid` claim to my access token?

Comment: Hi @JsonVorhees. Any luck with that, I've the same issue that I'm trying to solve ? Thanks